# Matplotlib 3D scatter plot animation is not moving

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation, data-visualization

I am a python beginner. This is my first time building a 3D scatterplot animation. In my code, I only want 6 points to display in a frame and remove points before the next frame comes. After writing the code, the problem came. The video is like a photo (see below) and shows every point.
Please help me, I don't know how to change my code.

[image]

[CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IP5l7Anyc_lfkPtuOrkj2tqre_ilO1vz/view?usp=sharing)

```
import os
import csv
from csv import reader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np  
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d') 
ax.set_xlim(0,100)        
ax.set_ylim(0,100)       
ax.set_zlim(0,100)      
dataname = open('/content/id3.csv', 'r')
data = csv.DictReader(dataname)
xr = []
yr = []
zr = []
xr1 = []
yr1 = []
zr1 = []
for col in data:
  xr.append(col['x'])
  yr.append(col['y'])
  zr.append(col['z'])
  xr1.append(col['x1'])
  yr1.append(col['y1'])
  zr1.append(col['z1'])    
x=[int(x) for x in xr]
y=[int(x) for x in yr]
z=[int(x) for x in zr]
x1=[int(x) for x in xr1]
y1=[int(x) for x in yr1]
z1=[int(x) for x in zr1]
def init():
    ax.scatter(x, y, z) 
    ax.scatter(x1, y1, z1) 
def run(data):
    ax.clear() 
    ax.set_xlim(0,100)         
    ax.set_ylim(0,100)        
    ax.set_zlim(0,100)        
    ax.scatter(x,y,z)
    ax.scatter(x1, y1, z1)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, frames=50, interval=30, init_func=init)  
ani.save('DREAMLINERs.mp4', fps=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit `run` function ad use `i` parameter as a counter: in each frame `i` increases by 1, so you can use it in order to select which point to plot in each frame. If you want to plot 6 points, whose coordinates come from `x`, `y`, `z` arrays, you can use:

```
ax.scatter(x[i:i + 6], y[i:i + 6], z[i:i + 6])
```

### Complete Code

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
ax.set_zlim(0,100)
dataname = open('/content/id3.csv', 'r')
data = csv.DictReader(dataname)

xr = []
yr = []
zr = []
xr1 = []
yr1 = []
zr1 = []
for col in data:
  xr.append(col['x'])
  yr.append(col['y'])
  zr.append(col['z'])
  xr1.append(col['x1'])
  yr1.append(col['y1'])
  zr1.append(col['z1'])
x=[int(x) for x in xr]
y=[int(x) for x in yr]
z=[int(x) for x in zr]
x1=[int(x) for x in xr1]
y1=[int(x) for x in yr1]
z1=[int(x) for x in zr1]


def init():
    ax.scatter(x, y, z)
    ax.scatter(x1, y1, z1)

def run(i):
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(0,100)
    ax.set_ylim(0,100)
    ax.set_zlim(0,100)
    ax.scatter(x[i:i + 6], y[i:i + 6], z[i:i + 6])
    ax.scatter(x1[i:i + 6], y1[i:i + 6], z1[i:i + 6])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, frames=50, interval=30, init_func=init)
ani.save('DREAMLINERs.mp4', fps=10)

plt.show()
```

### Animation

[image]

### Notes

You can simplify the code by using [**`pandas`**](https://pandas.pydata.org) to read data from `csv` file:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data/id3.csv')

x = data['x']
y = data['y']
z = data['z']
x1 = data['x1']
y1 = data['y1']
z1 = data['z1']
```